# min-height : min-content not work in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

**this is my code and min-height:min-content not work
and i use the working draft documentation -> CSS Box Sizing Module Level 3**

```css
article {
 border:1px solid blue;
}

article * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<article style="height:100px; min-height:min-content;">
  <aside style="height: 200px;">
    <div style="height: 150px;"></div>
  </aside>
  <section style="height: 30px;"></section>
</article>
```

**But if min-content is not used, it will work for example**

```css
article {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

article * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<article style="height:100px; min-height:400px;">
  <aside style="height: 200px;">
    <div style="height: 150px;"></div>
  </aside>
  <section style="height: 30px;"></section>
</article>
```

Comment: This will not work because you have specified the height to `height:100px` min-heights will not work if there is a value in `height` property.

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano actually min-height does work if height is specified. Try height: 100px and min-height: 500px - the element will have height of 500px. What seems to not be working as in the question is when min-height: min-content is used after setting an explicit height. If we swap them round so height: min-content and min-height: 100px that works as expected.

Comment: where in the Spec there is an example using min-content: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#sizing-values ?

Comment: the link of the section please

Comment: @TemaniAfif 
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#min-percentage-contribution
Slightly lower than this

Comment: @TemaniAfif You have an whats app account?

Comment: why you need my whats app?

Comment: @TemaniAfif   Was the answer to the problem found?

Comment: I want to form a group in whatsapp

Comment: no I don't have any answer yet

Answer (score 1):

`min-height: min-content` does not seem to be working when an explicit height has been set for the element.

However, if we swap these values round:

```
height: min-content; min-height: 100px;
```

things seem to work as expected. i.e. the height of the element will not be less than 100px but it will otherwise take on the min-content height.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <article style="height:100px; min-height:500px; background-color:cyan;">
          <aside style="height: 200px;">
            <div style="height: 150px;"></div>
          </aside>
          <section style="height: 30px;"></section>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should work because this is similar to the example used in w3c documentation and chrome and firefox support min-height: min-content

Comment: I agree, but it seems it doesn’t, would be good if someone could explain why, I’m stumped.